# Flask, Python and Socket.io: getting “RuntimeError: working outside of request context” when disconnecting from a threading.Timer

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, flask-socketio

I'm trying to write a simple server that disconnects a user after a min of inactivity.
ive found a simple way of doing it with threading.Timer (restarting the timer every time there is an activity).

im getting RuntimeError when using disconnect in a Timer.
tried using app.app_context and app.test_request_context but either I don't know how and where to use them or it simply doesn't work.

server code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, disconnect
from threading import Timer

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
sio = SocketIO(app)
clients = {}


class Client:
    def __init__(self, user, sid, client_time):
        self.user = user
        self.sid = sid
        self.client_time = client_time
        self.activity_timer = Timer(10, self.disc_after_60)
        self.start_timer()

    def disc_after_60(self):
        disconnect(self.sid)
        del clients[self.user]

    def start_timer(self):
        if self.activity_timer.is_alive():
            self.activity_timer.cancel()
            self.activity_timer.start()
        else:
            self.activity_timer.start()


@sio.on('register')
def handle_register(client_user, client_time):
    clients[client_user] = Client(client_user, request.sid, client_time)
    emit('message', ("SERVER", f"{client_user} has joined the server!"), broadcast=True)
```

client side I just connect using register.

the full error message:

```
Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\idshi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\idshi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 1254, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\idshi\PycharmProjects\PyChat excersize\Server\fsserver.py", line 24, in disc_after_60
    disconnect(self.sid)
  File "C:\Users\idshi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 919, in disconnect
    socketio = flask.current_app.extensions['socketio']
  File "C:\Users\idshi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 348, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "C:\Users\idshi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 307, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "C:\Users\idshi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 52, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

I would be glad if someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace and error message.

Comment: @Miguel added as requested

Answer (score 0):

The `disconnect()` function needs to be called with an application context installed, as that's the only way to know what's the application instance.

Try this:

```py
    def disc_after_60(self):
        with app.app_context():
            disconnect(sid=self.sid, namespace='/')
        del clients[self.user]
```

Comment: thanks, it works. I did the same thing but didn't include the namespace and got a "RuntimeError: Working outside of request context." so I assumed it doesn't work.

Comment: while this indeed works and disconnects the user, i am getting a different error message on the server, tho it doesnt seem to affect anything.
im getting- 
encoded_packet = pkt.encode(b64=b64)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
i have made sure the disconnect function is the reason for this error but i dont know why and havent found anything about this